# Not able to retrieve POST value after form POST --> PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, post

i have a form with an input box which will double when clicking on add button , something like below

[image: UI]

So it will keep on adding UTM ID, and when when i submit the form , the data should be fetched and printed using PHP , but Form gets posted but data is not passed .

So below is my code

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="basic-repeater" >
<select class="js-example-basic-single">
<option>Select Instance </option>
</select>
<div data-repeater-list="group-a">
div data-repeater-item>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="name">UTM ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name" placeholder="UTM Id">
    <button type="submit" name="SaveModules" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
    </form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['SaveModules'])){
       $UTMID = $_POST['name']; // value not getting retrieved 
       echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".$UTMID."' );</script>";
  }
?>
```

So Can anyone help me to figure out the issue

Comment: Do you get any error(s), say... _Notice: Array to string conversion_? What debugging have you done?

Comment: Could you tell us what is in $_POST right at the start of your PHP code?

Comment: No i didn't get any error @berend

Comment: it should be contents of UID but yeah am not geting it @Trukken

Answer (score 1):

I checked this code in local with multiple names and i got the correct array

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="basic-repeater" >
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
    <label for="name">UTM ID</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name" placeholder="UTM Id">   
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name1" placeholder="UTM Id">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name2" placeholder="UTM Id">  
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name[]" id="name3" placeholder="UTM Id">  
    <button type="submit" name="SaveModules" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
</div>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['SaveModules'])){
   $UTMID = $_POST['name'];
   print_r($_POST);
   //echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".$UTMID."' );</script>";
}
?>
```

and i got the result in post

```
[name] => Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 34 [2] => 56 [3] => 78 ) [SaveModules] => )
```

and if you need the array in javascript then you need to use json_encode because you can not print php array direct in console.log

```
echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".json_encode($UTMID)."' );</script>";
Debug Objects: ["rret","dfgdfg","dfgfg","ghvnv"] index.php:12:9
```

Comment: Array ( [group-a] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name]  => Array ( [name[]  ) ) [SaveModules] => )

Comment: am getting like this

Comment: i think so you need to post the exact form of input because in your question form tag there is no possibility of group-a might be you use something different in form is it possible to show exact code here so that i can get an idea.

Comment: Hi sejal , i just edited the code . Can u just take a look on to it

Comment: i think so you use any jquery for add more right? data-repeater-list="group-a" may be something working in hidden tag can you check

Comment: am actually getting the value but when i write debug console am not , but  when i write print_r($_POST) then it prints

Comment: did you try echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".json_encode($UTMID)."' );</script>";
?

Answer (score 0):

The code don't work because name input (`name="name[]"`) is multiple so in php will be an array.
if you do like that you will see all work because will take the first value of array:

```
echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".$UTMID[0]."' );</script>";
```

Instead if you want multiple ids use a `foreach` like:

```
if (isset($_POST['SaveModules'])) {
    $UTMID = $_POST['name']; // value not getting retrieved 
    foreach($UTMID as $id){
        echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: " . $id . "' );</script>";
    }
}
```

Another *"tips"* is to don't mixup like that `php/js`, if you need return in `js` use `AJAX` instead, or if you need to debug it use simple `echo`

Comment: yeah i tried this , but not getting , it just prints debug objects in console

Comment: All work like my example, you have another problem

Comment: Just edited the code , can u just take a look

Answer (score 0):

**name=name[] will be an array.**

```
$name[number] //to retrieve array values
```

**Multiple input with same name.**

You can set name=value[]

**Then you can retrieve the value with.**

```
val[0] //leads to the first value
```

**This is sample php got implode array value**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['SaveModules'])){

    $VAL= $_POST['name']; 
   
    $UTMID = implode(', ',$VAL);
    
        echo $UTMID; //output = Value1, Value2, Value3
   
  // echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".$UTMID."' );</script>";       
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try changing your name="name[]" to something like name="UTM" as you are looking for `name[]` and also requesting `name`
As for the multiple posts, you could add in your script that makes a new input box and add *n* after UTM, this would be good as you also know which box they are filling in.

Here:

```
<form method="POST" action="" class="basic-repeater" >
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 form-group">
<label for="name">UTM ID</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="UTM1" id="name" placeholder="UTM Id">
<button type="submit" name="SaveModules" class="btn btn-primary" >Update</button>
</form>

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['SaveModules'])){
       $UTMID = $_POST['UTM1']; // value not getting retrieved 
       echo "<script>console.log('Debug Objects: ".$UTMID."' );</script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you see in image of question, you will see he need multiple id

Comment: Apologies, I read the code, not the image - could navigate around that by adding _n_ after UTM?

Comment: but when i checked in other sites and some of stack it says just we need to use array for that , and also i did in dropdown list which is almost same @SimoneRossaini , and yeah that input box count is dynamic and not static

Comment: Look my answer @GowriLakshmi (use foreach)